# Gitlab: how to correct a bad squash commits

Tags: git, gitlab

I am new to using git,
I was squashing my commits, and i added commit that should not be added in this commit squash.

How can i please reinitialize this commit squash or, delete simply the bad file.
Please if you have an idea don't hesitate.

Thank you,

**code**

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
git push origin mybranch
```

Answer (score 0):

git rebase --abort

Then, delete your bad file, and try again

Comment: Thank you for your response @ignoring_gravity . Should i do it on master on my branch?

Comment: im gotting this error **fatal: No rebase in progress?**

Comment: Were you on `mybranch` when you did `git rebase -i HEAD~3`?

Comment: either way, maybe you can just delete your bad file and try again now then

Comment: how to delete a file from pushed commit ? because i did **git reset HEAD est.py** and i have still the when i did **git show 44933f6a68e2cca5aa7aaaaa322373f --name-only**

Comment: if you've already staged the file, you can delete it with `git rm -f my_bad_file`. note that this will permanently delete your file

Comment: i need the file in my project. I just want to delete it from just the last commit . will this command **git rm -f my_bad_file** delete it from my project definetively?

Comment: ah, in that case `git rm --cached my_bad_file` - it will no longer be staged but you'll still have it locally

Comment: this command **git rm --cached my_bad_file** also deleted it locally . I tried it now :(

Comment: are you sure? the docs https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm say "Use this option to unstage and remove paths only from the index. Working tree files, whether modified or not, will be left alone."

Comment: when i type git status on my branch **On branch my_branch
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
 deleted:    est.py**

Comment: yeah, it's been removed from git's index, but it should still be there if you look inside your folder

Comment: Its weird :/ then on my branch i did **git add good_file.py** and git commit "new commit" . when i type **git show 099985650deoooooood116c17561fb04183afll --name-only** I found only the bad_file.py

Comment: @ ignoring_gravity do you see what i mean ?

Comment: what's `099985650deoooooood116c17561fb04183afll `? Is that the _only_ commit you made after you did `git rm`?